# knitr: calling a ggplot2 function in a loop doesn't plot when accompanied by certain other plotting functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I'm not sure if this is a true bug or I'm missing something, but here it goes.
I have a ggplot function (plot_data) that I'd like to call in a loop. I've included the function in its own chunk. Calling the function works fine in a loop in case one (the chunk titled "works"), in this case the plot_data function is followed by a barplot. However, in the second case, the plot_data() function is followed by a heatmap in which case, but the heatmap, oddly, suppresses the plot_data function. This happens whether or not plot() or print() is called around the plot_data function.

Is there a way to get ggplots to behave with knitr? And how in the hell is a function call suppressing the output of a previous function call?

The following code reproduces the error for me:

```
[preamble omitted]
\begin{document}

<<setup, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
plot_data <- function(data) {
    require(ggplot2)
    require(reshape)
    d.melt <- melt(data)
    ggplot(data=d.melt, aes(x=X2, y=value, group=X1, colour=X1)) + geom_line(size=.5) +
          scale_x_discrete("") +
          scale_y_continuous("Value")
    }
@

<<works, echo=FALSE, results='asis', out.width='.3\\linewidth', dev='pdf', cache=TRUE >>=
set.seed(10010)
data <- matrix(runif(10000, 1,100), ncol=100)
for (i in 1:10) {
    ind <- sample(1:100, 10)
    plot(plot_data(data[ind,]))
    barplot(ind)
}
@

<<doesnt-work, echo=FALSE, results='asis', out.width='.3\\linewidth', dev='pdf', cache=TRUE >>=
set.seed(10010)
data <- matrix(runif(10000, 1,100), ncol=100)
for (i in 1:10) {
    ind <- sample(1:100, 10)
    plot(plot_data(data[ind,]))  # calling print instead of plot doesn't work either
    heatmap(data[ind,]  )
}
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a long shot, but is `par("ask")` TRUE?

Comment: Whats with the `<<setup>>` within each chunk (not that it changes the issue)?  why not set `eval = TRUE` in `setup` and not bother calling it after that?

Comment: sebastian-c: no par("ask") evaluates to false.

Comment: mnel: I was playing around with different ways to invoke chunk codes. Doing it the usual way, as you suggested has the same effect. I will edit the source code to reflect this.

Comment: interesting; could be a bug; you are welcome to send a note to https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues and I'll take a look at it in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you ask a lot from `knitr`. Aligning base graphics and grid graphics is not very easy and challenging in R. I don't know how `knitr` do it maybe using (package latex `graphics`), but what I think is when you call the `heatmap` , it is print in the same place of the grid plot.

Adding a `plot.new` before calling the base graphics works fine for me:

```
<<doesnt-work, fig.show='hold',out.width='.3\\linewidth'>>=
  set.seed(10010)
data <- matrix(runif(10000, 1,100), ncol=100)
for (i in 1:3) {
  ind <- sample(1:100, 10)
  print(plot_data(data[ind,]))  # calling print instead of plot doesn't work either
  plot.new()
  heatmap(data[ind,]  )
 }
@
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your function I think, the variables from the melt are off. This worked for me:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(10010)
data <- matrix(runif(10000, 1,100), ncol=100)
for (i in 1:3) {
   ind <- sample(1:100, 10)

   d.melt <- melt(data[ind,])
   p<-ggplot(data=d.melt, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, group=Var1, colour=Var1)) + 
      geom_line(size=.5) +
      scale_x_discrete("") +
      scale_y_continuous("Value")

   print(p)  
   plot.new()
   heatmap(data[ind,]  )
}
```